# how to add List<Integer> to List<List<Integer>>?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to solve Leetcode 113 Path Sum II. Here is the solution:

```
class Solution {
    List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<List<Integer>> pathSum(TreeNode root, int targetSum) {
        dfs(root, targetSum, new ArrayList<>());
        return res;
    }
    private void dfs (TreeNode node, int targetSum, List<Integer> list) {
        if (node == null) return;
        list.add(node.val);
        if (targetSum == node.val && node.left == null && node.right == null) {
          **  res.add(new ArrayList<>(list));**
        }else {
            if (node.left != null) dfs(node.left, targetSum - node.val, list);
            if (node.right != null) dfs(node.right, targetSum - node.val, list);

        }
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
    }

}
```

When I change `res.add(new ArrayList<>(list))` to `res.add(list)`, for example, I got res as `[[],[]]`, which should be like this `[[5,4,11,2],[5,8,4,5]]`.

Why I cannot use `res.add(list);` directly? list is defined by `ArrayList<>()`.

I checked related answers and know there are two ways to define a two dimensional array:

1. `List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`
2. `List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();`

And I know `List` is an interface, while `ArrayList` is a `Collection` class. I'm still confused about it.

Comment: And since you already have a `List<Integer>`, why don't you just `res.add(list)`?

Comment: if I use res.add(list), I will get  [[],[]] instead of like this [[5,4,11,2],[5,8,4,5]].

Comment: @TimRoberts I think that's OP's question.

Comment: You need a copy because you're clearing the original list at the end of `dfs()`.

Comment: For reference, the LeetCode problem is https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/ .

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer `dfs()` is being called recursively **with** a non-empty list, so creating a new list in it will not work; it could be a field variable instead, since it is always the same instance

Comment: @user16320675.  Thanks. I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... When I change `res.add(new ArrayList<>(list))` to `res.add(list)`, for example, I got res as `[[],[]]`, which should be like this `[[5,4,11,2],[5,8,4,5]]`. ..."*

This is because the *list* is an object, thus it will still be affected here,

```java
list.add(node.val);
```

And, here

```java
list.remove(list.size() - 1);
```

It can be confusing, as you'd imagine a new object value would be passed.

By using *`res.add(new ArrayList<>(list))`*, you are creating a new copy, of *list*—thus, it will not be affected.

Here is the source for that specific *ArrayList* constructor method.
*[GitHub – jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L180)*.

> *"... And I know `List` is an interface, while `ArrayList` is a `Collection` class. I'm still confused about it."*

You're correct.  Although, *List* is simply an interface *within* the *Collections* framework.
It still is, technically, a collection.

Here is the *List* JavaDoc.  *[List (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)*.

And, here is the JavaDoc for the *Collections Framework*.
*[java.util (Java SE 20 & JDK 20) – Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/package-summary.html#CollectionsFramework)*.

Finally, here is a Java Tutorial, on the *Collections Framework*.
*[Trail: Collections (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)*.